# Angular2 Return Inner Observable of Nested Observables

Tags: angular, observable

I want to make multiple http call in Angular2 using observables. Each observable is dependent on the prior observable. If I want to return the inner observable, so I can subscribe to it in the parent component), how can this be done?

Here is what I've tried, but I wasn't able to subscribe to the observable in the parent component.

Child Component:

```
observablesFn(){
   observable1().subscribe(data1 => {
        observable2().subcribe(data2 => {
            //I want to return this observable (before subscription b/c I want to subscribe in the parent component)
            return observable3();
        })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand since you haven't given much context, but it sounds like you're looking to get the result of `observable3()` to return from `observablesFn()`. The existing `return` statement is returning from your nested inner anonymous function, not your outermost scope. I think you're looking to do something more along these lines.

```
observablesFn(){
  return observable1().map(data1 => {
    return observable2(data1).map(data2 => {
      return observable3(data1, data2);
    });
  });
}
```

This will return from `observablesFn()`, rather than its nested inner function.

It's necessary to use `.map` rather than `.subscribe`, since it returns an observable, rather than a subscription.